# Matching groups on comma

Tags: regex

I have this string that will be structured like this:

`somevalue, secondvalue, thirdvalue`

There will always be three values and they will be comma seperated.
The actual values them self may also contain `,`s.

Some example of data that I have using this structure:

`app.weeks = 999, 999, app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7)`

Where  `app.weeks = 999` is one whole value followed by a `,`
and
`999` is one whole value followed by a `,`

and

`app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7)` is another value.

Using this string as an example, and with the structure above.

Keeping in mind, the values are not fixed, is not always going to conatin the word 'app.weeks = 999}'

I want to split this into three sections.

```
matches (
    $1: app.weeks = 999
    $2: 999
    $3: app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7)
)
```

The may come in any order:

```
999, app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7), app.weeks = 999

app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7), app.weeks = 999, 999
```

Or a combination:

```
app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7), app.weeks = 999, app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7)
```

In such cases it still needs to match like this:

```
matches (
    $1: app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7)
    $2: app.weeks = 999
    $3: app.weeks - FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), app.register) / 7)
)
```

The above are requirements of the application.

This is my attempt:

```
^(.+,)(.+,)(.+)$
```

But it does not match anything. What should my regex be?

On a side note, background into this requirement is I am trying to convert MYSQL IF statements into TSQL Case statements on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for clarifying your question.

Basically what you wish to find is everything between commas which aren't inside parenthesis.

The regex

```
(?<capture>[^,()]+(?<par>\((?:[^()]*(?&par)*)*\))?)
```

should do the trick.

Note that it splits the data into two tags:

- capture: this is the data you asked for
- par: this is the parenthesis that might exist, it is used for recursion in the regex but should be uninteresting to you.

[In action](https://regex101.com/r/kS7xW9/1)